# Error compiling for any board arduino ide 1.8.9

Tags: arduino-ide, compilation-errors

my arduino ide Until yesterday it worked properly . but today All previous projects   dont compiling and all of them have one error : Error compiling for  board 
and It's no different that Which board I choose in all of board i have this error .
please help me .

image link : http://uupload.ir/files/6hjr_capture1.jpg
error : * Error while detecting libraries included by C:\Users\ali_m\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_706504\sketch\timer.ino.cpp

- xtensa-lx106-elf-g++: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory
- Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module).

Comment: is it just ESP based boards that you can't compile for?

Comment: No for all of the boards this is hapen

Comment: Can you show the error for an arduino board

Comment: image link : http://uupload.ir/files/9aht_capture33.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I hope this [link](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=593072.0) helps you or please try a fresh install.